# Show that $V=Z(x;T)\oplus Z(y;T)$ and the $T$-annihilators $\mu_{T,x},\,\mu_{T,y}$ do not share any common divisors implies that $V$ is cyclic

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Provided that $V=Z(x;T)\oplus Z(y;T)$ where $Z(v;T)$ denotes the cyclic subspace and the corresponding $T$-annihilators $\mu_{T,x},\,\mu_{T,y}$ do not share any common divisors, show that $V$ is itself cyclic.

---

My approach was to first identify a possible cyclic vector, which was $x+y$ in this case. I then tried to show that every element of $V$ is an element of the cyclic vector space spanned by $T^jx+y,\ j\in\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ but the problem seems to be the condition that the $T$-annihilators $\mu_{T,x},\,\mu_{T,y}$ do not share any common divisors.

How do I apply this or how do I continue?

---

**Edit:** Definition of the $T$-annihilator as in [T-Annihilators and Minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010121/t-annihilators-and-minimal-polynomial) :

> **Definition**: $T$-annihilator of a vector $\alpha$(denoted as  $p_\alpha$) is the unique monic polynomial which generates the ideal
> such that $g(T)\alpha = 0$ for all $g$ in this ideal.

Comment: I'm guessing $Z(x,T)$ means the cyclic subspace generated by $x$ as a module, so spanned by $x,Tx,T^2x,\cdots$. What is $\mu_{T,x}$?

Comment: @runway44 I've added the definition to the question.

Comment: ? Chinese Remainder Thm ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the field is $k$, then $\pi_x:k[t]\to Z(x;T)$ by $p(t)\mapsto p(T)x$ is onto with kernel $\mu_{T,x}(t)$, so that $Z(x;T)\simeq \frac{k[t]}{\langle \mu_{T,x}(t)\rangle}$ and similarly for the other factor.

What you want to prove is that, if these minimal polynomials are coprime, then
$$
\frac{k[t]}{\langle \mu_{T,x}(t)\rangle}
\oplus
\frac{k[t]}{\langle \mu_{T,y}(t)\rangle}
\simeq
\frac{k[t]}{\langle \mu_{T,x}(t)\mu_{T,y}(t)\rangle};
$$
this is just the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** It suffices to show that $Z(x+y;T)$ contains both $x$ and $y$. To that end, note that the restrictions $\mu_{T,x}(T) \mid_{Z(y;T)},\mu_{T,y}(T) \mid_{Z(x;T)}$ are invertible.